# How to delete a cloned file on my Macbook

Tags: git

I cloned a repo from Gitlab into my Macbook using the git clone URL command. After that, I deleted the folder of the cloned repo on my Macbook by putting the folder into the trash bin and emptying it. However, when I enter the command ls -a on my Macbook, I can still see it. I'm still new to Git so I have no idea what I'm doing. May I know if there's a way for me to see that folder again or delete it permanently?

Comment: Are you saying when you open a new terminal, typing "ls -a" shows your (deleted) repo? Or is this in a terminal that was already open? Could it be that you simply cloned the repository twice?

Answer (score 0):

You can delete directories and their contents from the Terminal using `rm -R directoryname` Because it is a git repo, you probably would want to add `-f` to suppress warnings because commits are stored as write-protected files if I remember correctly. However, be **very** careful when dealing with files on the command line because it’s possible to delete things you didn’t want to. You could also make sure this is the repository that you downloaded by `ls directoryname` to see the contents before deleting it. It’s possible that the reason that you can’t see this file in Finder is because it somehow got hidden. To (possibly) reverse this, you can use Shift-Command-. (in a finder window in the folder that it was cloned into) to show hidden files.

Comment: Okay, I'll give it a try. Thank you!